# Order of a general element in the units group mod $2^k$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-number-theory, finite-groups

Is there any formula for the order of a general element in the units group modulo $2^k$ with $k\geq 3$?

Thanks

Comment: Hint: $\mathbb Z_{2^k}^*\simeq \mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_{2^{k-2}}~$ for $k\ge 2$.

Comment: Thank you Corvus. I am familier with this ispmorphism, still can't get how this leads to a general formula. Maybe you can write the formula?

Comment: What do you mean by "general element"?

Comment: By general element i mean an odd number $0<a<2^k$ namely a is an element in the units group $mod 2^k$.  I am trying to find if there is a function: a -> ord(a).

Comment: Why is this being downvoted? It seems like a reasonable question.

Comment: It’s not considered cricket to ask a naked question in this way: people like to see how much you know, and what you’ve tried so far. I for one like to see whether you’ve looked at even so many as one case of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a good rule, and it’s simply that if $m\equiv1\pmod{2^{k-d}}$ but $\not\equiv1\pmod{2^{k-d+1}}$ for $1\le d\le k-2$, i.e. $2\le k-d<k$, then the order of $m$ in the multiplicative group of units modulo $2^k$ is $2^d$. For odd numbers that are $\equiv3\pmod4$, look at $-m$ instead.

The rule above is better expressed in the language of the $2$-order $v_2$: if $w=2^ty$ with $y$ odd, we say that $v_2(w)=t$. Now the rule is that the order of $m$ in $(\Bbb Z/(2^k))^\times$ is $2^{k-v_2(m-1)}$. Let’s try it for $k=5$: the order of $25$ is $2^{5-v_2(24)}=2^{5-3}=4$, just right. You still need to worry about the case $m\equiv3\pmod4$, though.

And now that I’ve told you the way things fit together, you should go home and prove that what I say is true.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a reference for a book discussing this?

Comment: I don’t, offhand. You can prove it yourself. The key is that when $v_2(w-1)=e\ge2$, then $v_2(w^2-1)=e+1$. Believe me, you can easily prove that.